# How to insert picture as your bullet in a list

Tags: html, html-lists

I am currently creating a list within a table in HTML and I understand that in  order to create a bullet that I will have to use the following syntax.

```
<li><p>The table element was not designed to be a layout tool. </p></li>
<li><p>The table element is a layout tool. </p></li>
```

The following code will have an output display as shown below:

> The table element was not designed to be a layout tool.
>
> The table element is a layout tool.

However, am I able to change the bullet to a customized image? How am I able to do that if it is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can, use `list-style-image`:

```
ul {
    list-style-image: url('path/to/your/image');
}
```